# Cannot Getting data from url query parameters. from a node rest api

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have this code to make a get, post, put and delete request,

```
const express = require("express");
const TutorialModel = require("../models/tutorialModel");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/tutorials", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tutorial = new TutorialModel(req.body);
    const createTutorial = await tutorial.save();
    res.status(201).send(createTutorial);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

router.get("/tutorials", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const TutorialsData = await TutorialModel.find();
    res.status(200).send(TutorialsData);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(404).send(e);
  }
});

router.get("/tutorials/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const _id = req.params.id;
   const TutorialData = await TutorialModel.findById(_id);

    if (!TutorialData) {
      res.status(404).send();
    } else {
      res.send(TutorialData);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

router.get("/tutorials/:title", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const _title = req.params.title;
    const TutorialData = await TutorialModel.find({ title: _title });

    if (!TutorialData) {
      res.status(404).send();
    } else {
      res.send(TutorialData);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

router.put("/tutorials/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const _id = req.params.id;
    const updateTutorial = await TutorialModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      _id,
      req.body,
      { new: true }
    );
    res.send(updateTutorial);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

// Deleting student data by its Id

router.delete("/tutorials/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const _id = req.params.id;
    const deleteTutorial = await TutorialModel.findByIdAndDelete(_id);
    if (!_id) {
      return res.status(400).send();
    } else {
      res.send(deleteTutorial);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

router.delete("/tutorials", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const deleteTutorial = await TutorialModel.remove();
    if (!deleteTutorial) {
      return res.status(400).send();
    } 
    else {
      res.send(deleteTutorial);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I've successfully made all request including get request with 'id' But when I try to make get request using 'title' parameter I'm getting data of get request of "/tutorials" not of "tutorials/:title". What is the issue? Can anyone tell me please?

Comment: You're aware you have two `router.delete()` calls with the same signature, yes? I'm guessing the second one overrides the first

Comment: /tutorials/:id and tutorials/:title have the same signature, i'd expect /tutorial/:id is called if you specify a path param

Comment: Yeah! I've got my answer. The  "/tutorials/:id"  is catching all get requests and not distinguishing the params I passed here like "title" or anything else. So, I've changed the route url from "tutorials/title" to "findByTutorial/title" and got my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The route GET `"/tutorials/:id"` will catch **all** your GET requests like `/tutorials/something`. It does not distinguish if you pass an `id` or a `title`.

`:id` is used to tell Express to capture the `something` path in the URL in `req.params.id`. That's all.

If you want to have another route to get tutorials by title, you should use another form. For example, GET `"/tutorialsByTitle/:title"`.